# using id instead of custom class in for loop

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, uikit

I'm developing an app for iOS > 5.0 and using Xcode 4.6.2 & I've a `UIView` that contains a bunch of `UIKit` elements.

To give an example, i have a custom  class called `RadioButton` whose base class is `UIButton` as you imagine. I've also a class called `CRTLabel` which is a subclass of `UILabel`.

When i `po [view subviews]` in the console , i got

```
$0 = 0x0754c4d0 <__NSArrayM 0x754c4d0>(
<CRTLabel: 0x857f120; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (10 10; 360 35); text = '2- Sizce evet mi hayır mı...'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x857f1b0>>,
<RadioButton: 0x857f520; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (20 65; 44 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x857f5e0>>,
<CRTLabel: 0x857f800; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (84 65; 600 44); text = 'Evet'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 122; layer = <CALayer: 0x857f740>>,
<RadioButton: 0x857fb50; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (20 139; 44 44); opaque = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x857fa60>>,
<CRTLabel: 0x857fd60; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (84 139; 600 44); text = 'Hayır'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 122; layer = <CALayer: 0x857fc60>>
)
```

I've for loop to iterate over all of the subviews of view. So i use this code ,

```
for(RadioButton *radioButton in view.subviews)
{
     if(radioButton.selected == YES && radioButton.tag == 0)
     // Does something
     else if(radioButton.selected == YES && radioButton.tag == 1)
     // Does something
}
```

My app's crashed saying that there is no selected property. I've used `isKindOfClass` method to test radioButton is kind of `RadioButton`. So, i found that it iterates all the subviews if it's not kind of `RadioButton`. To explain more, even if current subview is a `CRTLabel`, it steps over the next line, `CRTLabel` doesn't have property called `selected`, so it crashes.

So, my expectation was to eliminate all of classes which isn't `RadioButton` and it iterates only over `RadioButton`s.

So my question is that `what is the advantage of specifying a custom class in foreach loop in Objective-c` ? I can always use `id` in loop than check if id is kind of `RadioButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`view.subviews` will return an array sub views. It will include both your radio buttons, labels like anything which is the subview of `view`.

```
  for(RadioButton *radioButton in view.subviews) //  logically wrong since subView can be anything button,label...

  for(UIView *subView in view.subviews)
  { 
     // Iterate through all subViews

     if([subView isKindOfClass:[RadioButton class]])
      {
        //safe no crash
      }
  }
```

You cannot iterate through specific views(radioButton) only. As you said you can iterate through all the views and use `isKindOfClass` to identify a specific subView. Otherwise you should relay on **tag** property of the view to eleminate the iteration

Comment: No, but i need to iterate through RadioButton, i don't need to iterate through all of the UIViews

Comment: Not possible. You cannot iterate through specific subViews. Iterating all sub view wont make any problem.. Its fast enumeration. ignore it:)

Answer (score 0):

test for `isKindOfClass` before assginging

```
for(id radioButton in view.subviews)
{
    if(radioButton isKindOfClass: RADIOBUTTON)
    { 

     if((RADIOBUTTON *)radioButton.selected == YES && (RADIOBUTTON *)radioButton.tag == 0)
     // Does something
     else if((RADIOBUTTON *)radioButton.selected == YES && (RADIOBUTTON *)radioButton.tag == 1)
     // Does something
    }
}
```

Comment: i've already did that it's working now, i'm just wondering advantage of using custom class instead of using id.

Comment: oh, there's no advantage, rather a disadvantage, of doing wat you did, not very robust